# How to read top-level requirements (as from requirements.in) from setup.py and write back pinned requirements (as in requirements.txt)?

Tags: python, pip-tools

I have a package with a `setup.py` file and want to use `pip-tools` to pin my dependencies for production.

Let's say my `setup.py` looks as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pathlib
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    author="Foo",
    description="My package",
    install_requires=["package1==1.0", "package2==2.0"],
    extras_require={
        "top_level": ["package1", "package2"],
    },
    version="0.1.0",
)
```

How could I here track my top level requirements within a `setup.py` and write them back to the same file within the section `install_requires`? Would I just `pip-compile` from `setup.py` into a `requirements.txt` and read the contents from this file into `install_requires`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track top-level deps in `requirements.in` and use `pip-compile` to lock deps in `requirements.txt`. Then you can make a `setup.py` and use both requirements files accordingly. For example:

```
def get_requirements(filename) -> list[str]:
    ...

setup(
    author="Foo",
    description="My package",
    install_requires=get_requirements('requirements.txt'),
    extras_require={"top_level": get_requirements('requirements.in')},
    version="0.1.0",
)
```

See an example of Sentry's [setup.py](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/blob/e9b3bc368889e4af4e3e5f8c929dcf7b232c0e5c/setup.py).

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off not using a `setup.py` file at all, since as you've evidently found out, it'd be a bit fiddly to put your locked requirements back in there, not to mention there are more modern systems these days than running arbitrary code to set up a package.

Instead, I'd recommend (at the time of writing) to use [Hatch](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/) and [hatch-requirements-txt](https://pypi.org/project/hatch-requirements-txt/) (if you really want a requirements.txt; you could use `tomli_w` to just modify `pyproject.toml` too...). (You can convert a `setup.py` project to Hatch with `hatch new --init`.)

You can then do something like (untested, just an idea)

```
python -c 'import tomllib, pathlib; print(*tomllib.loads(pathlib.Path("pyproject.toml").read_text())["project"]["optional-dependencies"]["toplevel"], sep="\n")' | pip-compile -
```

to generate `requirements.txt` from the optional dependencies in the TOML file.

Comment: Do you think this is less effort than writing into a `requirements.txt`?